# How to bind or inject variables from service providers to model class laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection

I have this class called `Book` and I want to have one global variable sort of thing in that class which consist of an exchange rate (For whole data/model)
I am trying to use service containers to inject the variable in it but I am sort of loss here

I tried this code within `AppServiceProvider.php` in the `register()` method, but it doesn't work.

```
$variable = 'something';
$this->app->bind('App\Models\FrontEnd\Book', function ($app) {
    return new $variable;
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a global variable? There's probably a better way to do that. If you were to give more context to what you want to do, it's possible that someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

declare variable in inside class which you want like this:

```
class Book {
    public $variable;

    public function __construct($variable)
    {
         $this->variable= $variable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the callback function. so you can

```
$variable = 'something';
$this->app->bind('App\Models\FrontEnd\Book', function ($app) use ($variable){
    return new $variable;
});
```